# Find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^2 +x^3 +x^4 +\cdots)^5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have got stuck on this question, though I realise that I have probably got really close to an answer. This is how I approached it:
\begin{align*}f(x) &= (x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots)^5\\
&= x^{10}(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots)^5\\
&= x^{10}\left(\frac{1-x^{m}}{1-x}\right)^5\\
&= x^{10}(1-x^{m})^5(1-x)^{-5}.\end{align*}
Then I have used the binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}(1-x^{m})^5 &= \sum^5_{i=0}\binom{5}{i}(-1)^i(x^m)^i,\\
(1-x)^{-5} &= \sum^\infty_{j=0}\binom{4+j}{j}(x)^j.\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$f(x) = x^{10}\cdot\left(\sum^5_{i=0}\binom{5}{i}(-1)^i(x^m)^i\right)\cdot\left(\sum^\infty_{j=0}\binom{4+j}{j}x^j\right),$$
and as I work out coefficient of $x^n$ I arrive to:
$$[x^n] = \binom{5}{0} \binom{n-6}{n-10} $$
I think my answer is incomplete and unfortunately, I don't have a solution to check it. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: What is $m$ defined as?

Comment: @AlanAbraham I have just used it to display some arbitrary big number.

Comment: oh ok, you don't really need to do that (actually I don't think you should do that). This is because the ellipsis means that it is an infinite series. I got the same answer as you.

Comment: @AlanAbraham right! I see! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had before, we have
$$f(x)=(x^2+x^3+\ldots)^5$$
$$f(x)=x^{10}(1+x+\ldots)^5$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^{10}}{(1-x)^5}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^{10}}{(1-x)^5}$$
$$f(x)=x^{10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+4}{4}x^k$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+4}{4}x^{k+10}$$
Hence, the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom{n-6}{4}$

Comment: Your answer is exact but very "dry": you should use more sentences ; explain for example how you obtain $f(x)=x^{10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+4}{4}x^k$ (by 4 successive derivations ?) even if the OP has mentionned this formula.

Comment: OP (of Q, not A): You can refer to the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations) for some background on that second-to-last line.